# JDBC Batch update for One time data Conversion

Tags: java, performance, jdbc, batch-processing, data-conversion

I have got into a situation, which I need to do data conversion for nearly 500,000 records. Below is the process

> 1. From Java we will call the DB and get a set of records (Older data)
> 2. These records will be passed to a webservice as input
> 3. The webservice response will be updated into the DB (correct data)

I did some research on it and found that SQL Batch is a decent option for this.

What I have planned to do is

> 1. Add 10,000 records to a batch (preparedstmnt. addBatch ();) via for loop
> 2. Then do a commit (  con.commit();)
> 3. preparedstmnt.clearBatch()
> 4. And then go back to step one until entire records are completed

Dear experts , what do you of this approach.If you got some better idea pls do suggest me that also.
And also if you have some suggestion to keep in my mind while doing bulk update from java , Do let me know that also

**Also Do the  executeBatch() calls clearBatch() in the end ? Or do we need to call clearBatch explicitly at the end of each batch  before we start the next batch?**

Comment: Talking about Batch... why don't you just use Spring Batch? It's "no brainer". P.S. Sorry for breaking rules by recommending specific tool.

Comment: Ok I didnt think about that before :). This work will be a one time job. And I will be creating an executable jar to do this job.So do you suggest spring batch is a better option for this?.The estimate I have got for this task is very less :(

Comment: I recently had a very similar task . One thing you should have in mind is that depending on how big the records are , 10,000 records / batch might be too much considering the memory . My records where fairly medium, about 45 columns , so one thing i did was  , create some smaller test batches of 50 , 100... records  and with the given results , do the math for some big batches . @BranislavLazic has a good point since the framework has some advantages .

Comment: Thank yo Kibadachi :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, it would look something like this if you use Spring Batch. One of the advantages is as I said: "It's no brainer". Easy to implement and Spring driven which means it will fit nicely in your current architecture if it's Spring driven too. Here's aprox. how your case would look like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class DBBatchProcess {

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB");
        dataSource.setUsername("username");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");
        return dataSource;
  }

  @Bean
  public ItemReader<InputEntity> reader(DataSource dataSource) {
    // Use some database reader. Like JdbcCursorItemReader, JdbcPagingItemReader etc.
    return new MyDatabaseReader();
  }

  @Bean
  public ItemProcessor<InputEntity, OutputEntity> processor() {
    // Do your conversion. Convert values from incoming entity to outcoming entity.
    return new MyProcessor();
  }

  @Bean
  public ItemWriter<OutputEntity> writer() {
    // Receive outcoming entity from processor and write it to database. You can use JdbcBatchItemWriter for instance.
    return new MyDatabaseWriter();
  }

  // Create a step. Provide reader, processor and writer. Determine chunk size.
  @Bean
  public Step step(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, ItemReader<InputEntity> reader, ItemWriter<OutputEntity> writer,
            ItemProcessor<InputEntity, OutputEntity> processor) {

    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step")
                             .<InputEntity, OutputEntity>chunk(10000)
                             .reader(reader)
                             .processor(processor)
                             .writer(writer)
                             .build();
  }

  // Finally, create a job
  @Bean
  public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, Step step) {
      return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                       .start(step)
                       .build();
  }

}
```

In case of failure you can determine what to do. You can attach listeners to Steps or Jobs etc.